# Native PGFPlots in JULIA language changing font size

Tags: plot, julia

I am using the native PGFPlots.jl plotting software in Julia language.

I will be ever so grateful if you could let me know how to change the font size of:

1. Title (I suspect with legend style={font=\small})
2. legend
3. xlabel
4. ylabel

My code:

```
pushPGFPlotsOptions("scale=1.5")
Plot1 = GroupPlot(2, 2, groupStyle = "horizontal sep = 1.6cm, vertical sep = 2.cm")
push!(Plot1b, Axis([
Plots.Linear(Se, H_Kg, mark="none", style="red, very thick"),
Plots.Linear(Se, H_Vg, mark="none", style="dashed, blue, very thick"),
], title="Se(H)", xlabel=L"$Se[-]$", ylabel=L"$H[cm]$", style="smooth", xmin=Se_Min, xmax=Se_Max, ymin=H_Min, ymode="log"))

push!(Plot1, Axis([
Plots.Linear(Se, Kunsat_Kg, mark="none", style="red, very thick", legendentry=L"$KG$"),
            Plots.Linear(Se, Kunsat_Vg, mark="none", style="dashed, blue, very thick", legendentry=L"$VG$"),
], title="K(Se)", xlabel=L"$Se[-]$", ylabel=L"$K(Se)[cm/h]$", style="smooth", xmin=Se_Min, xmax=Se_Max, ymin=K_Min, legendStyle = "{at={(-0.3,-0.4)}, anchor=south west, legend columns=-1}"))
save(Path, Plot1)
```

Many thanks for any help you may provide,

Comment: Do mind that I could not run the code you posted. It helps a lot to be able to reproduce your problem, so I'd advice posting modified code with fake data as input.

Comment: It seems that arguments to the Plots.Label parameters xlabelStyle, ylabelStyle, and  legendStyle are passed to the underlying Tex package, so I'd consult the Tex package for how to parameterize the font size with arguments to those parameters.

Comment: If you are familiar with PGFPlots syntax and need more flexibility, consider using https://github.com/KristofferC/PGFPlotsX.jl